# Proof that there always exists a dominating policy in an MDP

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process, proofs, policies

I think that it is common knowledge that for any infinite horizon discounted MDP $(S, A, P, r, \gamma)$, there always exists a dominating policy $\pi$, i.e. a policy $\pi$ such that for all policies $\pi'$: $$V_\pi (s) \geq V_{\pi'}(s) \quad \text{for all } s\in S .$$

However, I could not find a proof of this result anywhere. Given that this statement is fundamental for dynamic programming (I think), I am interested in a rigorous proof. (I hope that I am not missing anything trivial here)

Comment: For what it's worth, a proof of this fact may be found in Chapter 6 of the book "Markov decision processes: Discrete stochastic dynamic programming" by Martin Puterman. To reproduce it here would take a quite a bit of effort due to the context required, I'm afraid.

Comment: @mikkola Maybe you can just sketch the idea of the proof, if you are familiar with it. I guess that would be enough for a formal answer (in addition to pointing to that chapter).

Answer (score 0):

I think the statement above is incorrect, it should be $\forall \; \pi \in \Pi $ and not $\forall \; s \in S $. Then the proof is trivial and we can show this by contradiction. Assume $V_\pi(s) < V_\hat\pi(s),\; \forall s \in S$ is always the case, i.e. $\nexists \pi \;\forall \;\hat\pi, s.t. V_\pi(s) \geq V_\hat\pi(s)$. This statement is wrong beacause for $\pi = \hat\pi$ the equality condition holds.
For the $>$ case, we can use the definition of $\pi^*$, optimal policy.